# VA interface (Computer Program) not connecting with Virtual Yoke (Android App)

Tags: dll, windows-10, superuser

I installed VA Interface v2.22.1.11622 on my computer and downloaded the Virtual Yoke app on my android smartphone. When I open the VA Interface control panel it is marked active and it declares that it is connected to FSX Steam Edition. When I open the app on my phone and try to connect to VA Interface (using the WIFI symbol on the top-left) it takes 1 minute which after there is a message saying "Auto connection failure" and it gives me the option to try connecting manually. I have tried both ways and cant get it to connect and work with the Flight Simulator. Did anybody else have a similar or the same problem? Could someone nudge me in the right direction if I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming. Maybe ask on SuperUser? Also: Not sure why you tagged this question as **fsxaml** - it has nothing to do with F#.

Comment: I am new to stack exchange. I don't understand what the tag is for. Could you tell me how to use them? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=What+are+tags

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!! You just need to go to firewall settings and allow private connections with this app. If anybody else having the same problem refers to this post I can give you a detailed explanation on how to get it to work.